# Android studio grid of buttons auto align

Tags: android, button, gridview

Say I want 3 rows and 3 columns of buttons so 9 buttons in total. If one button in any position is removed, how would I go about shifting them so there isn't a gap where the button once was? I can think of some lengthy and possibly unnecessarily complicated ways to achieve this in an activity. Is there a simpler way to do this through the layout file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that purely through XML code in Android but you can use a RecyclerView:

```
RecylerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerInActivity);

//now create a GridLayoutManager 
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this);

//set the gridLayoutManager's spanCount to 3 for 3 columns: 
gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(3);

//Now create your custom Adapter with an XML layout with a button and set the adapter 
recycler.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);

//When a view is removed, remove it from the data supply (e.g. arrayListOfData.remove(indexOfRemovedItem)) of the RecylerView.Adapter  and then call: 
myCustomAdapter.notifyItemChanged(indexOfRemovedItem);
```

The RecyclerView's built in animations will ensure the RecyclerView's layout adapts to the new item count